# Selecting a data entry on load event causes empty fill

Tags: highcharts

Why is the selected slice's fill empty? I've added an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6duaLvv/

No errors seem to occur (according to the chromium's console).

```
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie',
      events: {
        load: function() {
          this.series[0].data[0].select();
          this.redraw();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the afterAnimate event instead:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      afterAnimate: function() {
        this.data[0].select();
        this.redraw();
      }
    }
  }
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events

http://jsfiddle.net/xf2wc82n/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is casued by animation. You try to select the element before rendering and animate. The solution is call select() function after animate in the callback.

```
  function(chart){
          setTimeout(function() {
             chart.series[0].data[0].select();
          },1000);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1oyqs8t3/